# How to share content from other social medias to my flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart, webview, social-media

I'm trying to find a way to share content from other social medias (e.x. TikTok, Instagram, Facebook etc) to my flutter app, now what I can't figure out is how to first get the url link of that post that is on other social medias into my app, then display an image/frame/thumbnail of that video into my app and lastly when I click that thumbnail/frame/image it will redirect me to that post through a web-view.

What I got so far is just a WebView widget from the [webview_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) package with which I'm trying to get only the first frame of the video and display it on the screen then when I click on it redirect me to the actual post through a WebView but so far no luck on this from my side :(.

Does anyone have any idea how do I even start or solve this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use share_plus package
https://pub.dev/packages/share_plus but i think u cant customized the UI